# AngularJS - How can i refactore my Jasmine specs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, specifications

I use AngularJS 1.2.16 with Jasmine 2.X for my javascript specs.
But they quickly turned messy. I am having a hard time finding information on how to refactor and structure the specs.

Here are some bad specs of mine:

```
  channel = mockRestangular = $httpBackend = deferred = undefined
  channel_id = {...}

  beforeEach ->
    module("channels", ($provide) ->
      mockRestangular = {
        configuration: { baseUrl: "" }
        one: ->
          this
        post: ->
          this
        put: ->
          this
        ...
      }

      module ($provide) ->
      $provide.value('Restangular', mockRestangular)
      return
    )

  beforeEach inject((_channel_, $q, $injector) ->
    channel = _channel_
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend')
    deferred = $q.defer()
  )

    it "spec1", inject(($q, $rootScope) ->
      deferred = $q.defer()
      spyOn(mockRestangular.one().one(), 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
      spyOn(channel::, 'init').and.stub()
      new_channel = new channel(channel_id)
      new_channel.updateCount()
      deferred.resolve({"channels":[{...long...long...object...}]})
      $rootScope.$digest()
      expect(new_channel.meta.totalProducts).toEqual(24849)
      expect(new_channel.meta.activeProducts).toEqual(1349)
    )

    it "spec2", inject(($q, $rootScope) ->
      deferred = $q.defer()
      spyOn(mockRestangular.one().one(), 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
      spyOn(channel::, 'init').and.stub()
      new_channel = new channel(channel_id)
      new_channel.updateStatisticsRevenue()
      deferred.resolve({"revenue_statistics":[{...another...very...very...long...object...}]})
      $rootScope.$digest()
      expect(new_channel.statistics.revenue).toEqual([{...kinda...long...object...result...}])
    )

  # spec with real respond-mock objects
  describe "describtor2", ->
    it "spec3", inject(($rootScope) ->
     $httpBackend.expectPUT().respond(201,
  {products:[{"sku":"10413161","active":false,"min_price":{"fractional":400,"currency":"EUR"},"max_price":{"fractional":950,"currency":"EUR"}},{"sku":"10413162","active":true,"min_price":{"fractional":458,"currency":"EUR"},"max_price":{"fractional":799,"currency":"EUR"}}]})
     spyOn(mockRestangular.one().one(), 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
     spyOn(channel::, 'init').and.stub()
     new_channel = new channel channel_id
     new_channel.updateProducts()
     new_channel.getMeta().activeProducts = 2
     expect(mockRestangular.one().one().get).toHaveBeenCalled
     deferred.resolve({"products":[{"sku":"10413161","active":true,"min_price":{"fractional":412,"currency":"EUR"},"max_price":{"fractional":890,"currency":"EUR"}},{"sku":"10413162","active":true,"min_price":{"fractional":448,"currency":"EUR"},"max_price":{"fractional":799,"currency":"EUR"}}]}
     )
     $rootScope.$digest()
     new_channel.updateProduct([{sku:"10413161",active:false,min_price:{fractional:400,currency:"EUR"},max_price:{fractional:950,currency:"EUR"}},{"sku":"10413162","active":true,"min_price":{"fractional":458,"currency":"EUR"},"max_price":{"fractional":799,"currency":"EUR"}}])
     $httpBackend.flush()
     expect(new_channel.getProducts()).toEqual(
[{"sku":"10413161","active":false,"min_price":{"fractional":400,"currency":"EUR"},"max_price":{"fractional":950,"currency":"EUR"}},{"sku":"10413162","active":true,"min_price":{"fractional":458,"currency":"EUR"},"max_price":{"fractional":799,"currency":"EUR"}}]
     )
     expect(new_channel.getMeta().activeProducts).toBe(1)
)
```

Because they are so long with all the objects in them I even start to put more "expects" into a single spec. I know that's wrong, but I am afraid of those huge specs.

Are there any best practices for structuring or refactoring Jasmine specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeforeEach` to put some initial common code of each spec, for instance, you could put those lines:

```
      deferred = $q.defer()
      spyOn(mockRestangular.one().one(), 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
      spyOn(channel::, 'init').and.stub()
      new_channel = new channel(channel_id)
```

in a `BeforeEach`, associated to the concerned `describe`.

```
beforeEach(function() {
      deferred = $q.defer();
      spyOn(mockRestangular.one().one(), 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
      spyOn(channel::, 'init').and.stub();
      new_channel = new channel(channel_id);
});
```

Other alternative: create some basic javascript function to gather common code.
The advantage would be that you could **name** those portions of code:

```
function mockDBGet() {
          deferred = $q.defer();
          spyOn(mockRestangular.one().one(), 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
}

function initChannel() {
          spyOn(channel::, 'init').and.stub();
          new_channel = new channel(channel_id);
}
//.......
it('myCurrentSpec', function(){
  mockDBGet();
  initChannel();   far more clean than your previous version
});
```

Comment: That `beforeEach` is good. For everyone who didn't know - as i did - every describe can have its own `beforeEach` functions. That other alternative sound interesting, could you give some example/further link?

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: Ohh ja. That's beautiful. Do you have some thoughts on how to handle larger mock-response-objects? I think if we could add this, you provided a A+ answer, concerning all my questions for me and possible others.

Comment: The idea is to emerge a hierarchy of specs. Look at this: http://www.bechte.de/2013/09/09/cleanup-your-junit-tests-by-using-contexts/ (Java example but really similar to Jasmine) Hierarchy of "context" with specific setup enables factoring of setups. (`beforeEach` in Jasmine term). => Don't hesitate to declare nested `describe` corresponding to a specific context, so that you can benefit from the initialization (mocks etc.) of the parents' ones.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was just wondering if there might be a nice solution for storing larger ( 200+ character mock responses ). Storing them in their own function|context might even be not enough for them. Just separating specs and mocks. Is there a best practice for that?

Comment: May you give me (in a comment) an exact example of what you call: large mock responses?

Comment: updated the question spec3 with the real mock objects.

Comment: a simple extract to variable ( in the beforeEach) should do the trick:  you declare var getResponse; outside the beforeEach, and in the beforeEach : getResponse = {...};   Then you can use this variable in your specs. You can even declare the response as a pure Javascript object and the convert it to Json through JSON.stringify

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Mik. superior answer.